# SubString error indexoutofbounds Java

Tags: java

I've decided to write my own subString method, however when I test it within my test driver I receive an error with one of my lines in my SubString method. This is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 6
at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
at unisa.util.StringImproved.subString(StringImproved.java:618)
```

This is my code for my subString:

```
    public String subString(int start, int end) {
    //empty string to append the new string's characters to
    String subString = "";
    //creating a new string to store content to allow function
    String s1 = new String(content);
    //read each character in the string and append based on the index
    for (int i=start; i<=end; i++){
        subString += s1.charAt(i);
    }
    //convert string back to a char array
    content = subString.toCharArray();
    return subString;

}
```

The error is picking up the line subString += s1.charAt(i); Anyone able to shed some light on what i'm doing wrong??

PS. this isn't for an assignment just a bit of boredom and wanting to re-create the java functions myself.

Thanks in advance!!

I have added my testing methods as per request!!

```
private int testSubString(String testID) {
    int errorCount=0;



    header(testID);

    {
        System.out.println("Test[getting substring from middle] ");
        StringImproved str = new StringImproved("0123456789");
        String result = str.subString(1,2);
        errorCount+=handleResult(result,"1")?0:1;
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Test[getting first characters] ");
        StringImproved str = new StringImproved("0123456789");
        String result = str.subString(0,2);
        errorCount+=handleResult(result,"01")?0:1;
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Test[getting last characters] ");
        StringImproved str = new StringImproved("0123456789");
        String result = str.subString(str.length()-3,str.length());
        errorCount+=handleResult(result,"789")?0:1;
    }


    {
        System.out.println("Test[out of range] ");
        StringImproved str = new StringImproved("0123456789");
        String result = str.subString(0,str.length()+1);
        errorCount+=handleResult(result,null)?0:1;
    }

    {
        System.out.println("Test[zero length source] ");
        StringImproved str = new StringImproved("");
        String result = str.subString(0,str.length()-1);
        errorCount+=handleResult(result,null)?0:1;
    }
    return errorCount;      
}
```

Comment: A bug is a discrepancy between actual behaviour and intended behaviour. Tell us what the intended behaviour is. There are perfectly valid reasons for throwing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` on occassion. Also tell us with wich values your are testing the method.

Comment: The intended behaviour @Oswald is to basically the method be functional enough that no matter what string I put into the test driver I have created it should create a substring of that string.

Comment: What if it cannot compute the substring in a natural way, e.g. because `start` is larger than the length of the input string or `end` is larger than the length of the input string or `start` is larger than `end`, or `start` or `end` is negative? You have to at least think about what your method should do in these cases. You can leave it unspecified; but then, throwing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is acceptable behaviour for the mentioned input values. I do not know with wich values you tested your method, so I have no clue to why throwing a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException` is wrong.

Comment: I have added my testing method in my original post if that helps. @Oswald

Comment: Follow the advice given by Maroun Maroun. When you have done that, you will also have to extend your method such that it examines the `start` and `end` arguments and the length of the input string so that you get the expected results in the cases *out of range* and *zero length source* (you return an empty string in those cases, but according to the tests you are doing, `null` is expected).

Answer (score 5):

Arrays are *zero-based*.

If your string is of length `N`, the indexes are from `0` to `N - 1` (Total length of `N`).

Your `for` loop should be:

```
                   ↓‎
for (int i=start; i<end; i++) {
```

Example:

`"This is a test"` is of size **14**, **T** is on the **0** place, the last **t** is the **13** place.

---

As @sanbhat mentioned, you need to check some cases, for example, what will happen it the size of `content` is smaller than `end`?

Comment: this will not work.. what if the length of `content` is smaller than `end` ?

Comment: @sanbhat This is to tell why exception occuring,Proper gaurd checkings needs to be placed by OP.We cannot cover all the things here :)

Comment: Atlest we can warn OP ? Above solution alone cannot fix the `IndexoutofBound` issue..isn't it? :)

Comment: @sanbhat  Yes,Thumsup santosh :)

Answer (score 2):

Change

```
for (int i = start; i <= end; i++){
   subString += s1.charAt(i);
}
```

to

```
for (int i = start; i < end; i++){
    subString += s1.charAt(i);
}
```

But this would be error prone, because it depends how do you invoke your own `substring()` method. The reason is that the parameters may exceed the length of the string (or be negative, for example).

A better approach is to make a couple of checks to **ensure** the parameters are valid.

```
if (start >= 0 && end >= start) {
   end = Math.min(myString.length(), end);
} else { 
   throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid arguments");
}
```

and the do the loops.

You should also note, that the `String#chatAt(int i)` method returns the character of the **zero-based** `char[]` array that represents the String object.

Comment: I made the change to the for loop but it's still returning an error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 10
 at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
unisa.util.testing.TestDriverPublic.testStringImproved(TestDriverPublic.java:108)

At the specific for loop.

Comment: How do you invoke the method ?

Comment: I'm not necessarily invoking them but putting the methods through tests with different strings if that makes sense.